# Property of a monotonic function

Tags: analysis

I am unable how to use the intermediate  value property  to prove the continuity  of the monotonic function 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/imSdL.jpg)

Comment: This Q has appeared on this site before. The IVP is sometimes called the Darboux property.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: prove that, for any $c\in(a,b)$, there exist
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)
$$
Use the intermediate value properly to show the limits are equal. Adjust for the boundaries.